# Build Angular app and publish on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, webpack, module, angular-cli

I'm trying to host my Angular app on IIS and read a lot to use the cli command ng build. This gives errors **Module not found**. When I change the templateUrl in the component the error is gone, but my application fails.

```
templateUrl: 'app/account/login.component.html'           (not building)
templateUrl: 'login.component.html'          (building, but app fails with unknown path)
```

In the beginning I had no **.angular-cli.json** file in my application so I just added one manually.

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"project": {
"name": "buildingprojects"
},
 "apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
}
],
"e2e": {
"protractor": {
  "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
}
},
"lint": [
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
},
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
},
{
  "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
}
],
 "test": {
"karma": {
  "config": "./karma.conf.js"
}
},
"defaults": {
"styleExt": "css",
"component": {}
}
}
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "buildingprojects",
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": "Nick Ausloos",
"description": "Building Projects",
"main": "src/index.html",
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack --progress --watch --config src/webpack.config.js",
"dev": "lite-server -c bs-config.json",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
"@angular/cli": "^1.4.8",
"@angular/common": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/forms": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/http": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/router": "^4.4.4",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"@types/adal": "^1.0.29",
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
"@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
"@types/node": "^8.0.31",
"adal-angular": "^1.0.15",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.3",
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-helpers": "^6.24.1",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
"concurrently": "^3.5.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.1",
"css-loader": "^0.28.7",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
"file-loader": "^1.1.4",
"free-jqgrid": "^4.14.1",
"html-loader": "^0.5.1",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"jsdo": "^4.3.12",
"lite-server": "^2.3.0",
"loader-utils": "^1.1.0",
"node-sass": "^4.5.3",
"postcss": "^6.0.12",
"postcss-cssnext": "^3.0.2",
"postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
"rxjs": "^5.4.3",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
"source-map-loader": "^0.2.2",
"style-loader": "^0.18.2",
"tslint": "^5.7.0",
"typescript": "^2.5.3",
"url-loader": "^0.5.9",
"webpack": "^3.6.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.17"
},
"dependencies": {
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"adal-angular": "^1.0.15",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.3"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thin you should follow this guid first https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-moving-into-the-cli where it shows you how to move into angular cli.

Jhon Papa published this guide to shows how to deploy to azure, is the same for iis https://johnpapa.net/deploy-angular-to-azure-vsts-angular-cli/

Comment: No solution! Following the first guide to convert into cli ends with the same error. Publishing to IIS is not the same as in Azure.

Comment: You must make ng build from the directory where is e.g. angular-cli.json

Comment: check my answer about tsconfig and testTsconfig

Comment: @Eliseo I'm doing the build from the root folder where the angular-cli file is located

Comment: Has you change tsconfig and testTSconfig?

Answer (score 0):

you can try change "base" tag in your index.html

```
<base href="./"/>
```

Comment: No solution with this answer! Keep getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

you have in angular.json

```
"tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
"testTsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
```

Maybe?

```
"tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
"testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> In the beginning I had no .angular-cli.json file in my application so I just added one manually.

It looks like you did not create the application using `ng new`. But you are trying to use `ng build`. I recommend you to create an Angular CLI application from scratch using `ng new`, test its deployment to IIS, than copy your custom components over to it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just replacing the paths with the file names. This way the build succeeded, but this was not a solution to publish it into IIS. With the webpack bundler, the files just need to be copied to the IIS folder. The only problem then is the routing of the components.